# Programming a PDE in Python with Brownian path

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint, pde

I'm currently trying to simulate a PDE including a Brownian path (one of the terms includes, that when going one timestep 'dt' further the change is weighted by a normal distributed variable with mean 0 and variance dt).

For this I used Fast Fourier Transform to get a system of ODEs which I can solve much more easily (at least that's what I thought). This lead me to the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#Defining some parameters a, b, c, which are included in the PDE

a = 10
b = 1.5
c = 20

#Creating the mesh

L = 100
N = 100
dx = L/N
x = np.arange(0, L, dx)

dt=0.01
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)


#Frequency for the Fourier Transformation

kappa= 2*np.pi*np.fft.fftfreq(N, d=dx)

#Initial condition for function u and its Fast Fourier Transformation

u0= np.zeros_like(x)
u0[int((L/4-L/10)/dx):int((L/4+L/10)/dx)]=2.5
u0[int((3*L/4-L/10)/dx):int((3*L/4+L/10)/dx)]=2.5
u0hat = np.fft.fft(u0)

u0hat_ri= np.concatenate((u0hat.real, u0hat.imag))

#Define the function describing the Transformation from the PDE to the system of ODEs

def func(uhat_ri, t, kappa, a, b, c):
    uhat = uhat_ri[:N] +(1j)*uhat_ri[N:]

#Define the weighted change by the Brownian path B

    mean = [0]*len(uhat)
    diag = [0.1] * len(uhat)
    cov = np.diag(diag)
    B = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)

    d_uhat = -a**2 * (np.power(kappa, 2))* uhat-c*(1j)*kappa*uhat + b* (1j) * kappa * uhat * B
    d_uhat_ri = np.concatenate((d_uhat.real, d_uhat.imag))
    return d_uhat_ri

#Solve the ODE with odeint

uhat_ri = odeint(func, u0hat_ri, t, args=(kappa, a, b, c))


uhat = uhat_ri[:, :N] + (1j) * uhat_ri[:, N:]

u = np.zeros_like(uhat)

#Inverse Transform the Solution

for k in range(len(t)):
    u[:, k] = np.fft.ifft(uhat[k, :])

u = u.real
```

This program works if I exclude the Brownian path B in func

```
def func(uhat_ri, t, kappa, a, b, c):
    uhat = uhat_ri[:N] +(1j)*uhat_ri[N:]
    d_uhat = -a**2 * (np.power(kappa, 2))* uhat-c*(1j)*kappa*uhat + b* (1j) * kappa * uhat
    d_uhat_ri = np.concatenate((d_uhat.real, d_uhat.imag))
    return d_uhat_ri
```

But it takes a long time to execute when including B and also it tells me:

C:\Users\leo_h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py:247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)

**EDIT/ANSWER:**

I solved the problem, by putting the change in the Brownian path out of `func`. I guess it was just too much for `odeint` to cope with the function (or it generated a new Brownian path for each `t`?)

```
mean = [0]*len(u0hat)
diag = [2] * len(u0hat)
cov = np.diag(diag)
B = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)


def func(uhat_ri, t, kappa, a, b, c, B):
    uhat = uhat_ri[:N] +(1j)*uhat_ri[N:]
    d_uhat = np.zeros_like(uhat)
    d_uhat = -a**2 * (np.power(kappa, 2)) * uhat-c * (1j) * kappa * uhat + b * B * (1j) * kappa * uhat
    d_uhat_ri = np.concatenate((d_uhat.real, d_uhat.imag))
    return d_uhat_ri


uhat_ri = odeint(func, u0hat_ri, t, args=(kappa, a, b, c, B))
```

Comment: I think the issue is one of the underlying mathematics - this is an SDE so you are not dealing with the usual Riemann integral. Probably better to try something like Euler-Maruyama.

Comment: I know that the underlying mathematics implies that it is a SDE, having a Brownian path however it becomes  a deterministic PDE (approximately). Btw. it is actually a SPDE that I'm trying to solve. After Transformation the solution to this SPDE was the solution of a Geometric Brownian motion, which somehow didn't work for me.

Comment: yes, so using a method based on Riemann integration will not work.

Comment: Since I only use an approximation of the Brownian path the Application of Riemann integration is ok.